# Any finite set of points in in the projective plane can be defined by two polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

According to an exercise in Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*

> [Prove that] any finite set of points $S\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ can be defined by two equations.

I need to prove this, but I'm struggling to even work out some examples, e.g.

- $\{[1:0:0]\}=\mathbb{V}(y,z)$
- $\{[1:0:0],[0:1:0]\}=\mathbb{V}(xy,z)$
- $\{[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[0:0:1]\}=\mathbb{V}(?,?)$

Any hints for proving the statement, or ideas for coming up with an algorithm for finding the two polynomials? (I would assume that a constructive proof is relatively easy to find, but this question is in the section about dimension in the book, so I'm guessing there might also be some sort of dimensional argument that is not necessarily constructive.)

Comment: Could induction work here?

Comment: First, this is not known if the base field is not algebraically closed and is a conjecture by Lyubeznik over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Secondly, this is a set-theoretic statement, not ideal-theoretic, the latter being obviously false. If you need a hint for the algebraically closed case, I will be happy to provide one. An ad hoc solution for the last one is $V(xy+yz+zx, xyz)$.

Comment: @Mohan ah that's a pretty obvious solution now I see it! and sorry, Shafarevich always assumes algebraically closed, so I forgot to mention that. Interesting that it's a conjecture for Q. What do you mean by ideal-theoretic?  A hint would be great!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I hadn't thought of that actually, do you have any sketch ideas for how you'd use it?

Comment: Nope, just spit balling. I played around but had other work to do.:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible theme. If there is only one  point, there is not much to do, so assume that there are at least two points. So, we may assume that one of the points is $[0:1:0]$ and all other points lie in the affine plane $z\neq 0$. After linear change of variables, you can also assume that the $x$-coordinates of all the points in finite distance are distinct, say $a_1,\ldots, a_n$. Then choose a sufficiently large degree polynomial say of degree $d\geq 2$, $f(x)$ so that $f(a_i)=b_i$, where $(a_i,b_i)$ are the points of interest. Then, let $F(x,z$ be the homogenization of $f$. I claim that the set in question is defined by $yz^{d-1}-F(x,z)$ and $\prod (x-a_iz)$.

Comment: wow, can I ask how you would come up with something like this? to be honest, I'm not even certain that I could prove your claim...

Comment: You can see that these equations define the points at finite distance well, but at $[0:1:0]$, they vanish to a high order, so these define the set set-theoretically, but these do not generate all polynomials vanishing at these points, which would mean ideal-theoretic. Set-theoretic questions are inherently harder and defy neat solutions at present.